# Is there a way to copy and paste text and images between two computers?

Tags: windows-7, osx-leopard, mac, copy-paste

I use a Windows 7 machine and an iMac at work.

Are there any applications that would allow me to copy and paste text and images from one computer to the other? Sometimes I have to share passwords or scripts across the two.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Synergy+](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/) is a program that allows you to share 1 mouse and 1 keyboard with several computers. One of its features is the sharing of the clipboard so you can copy on 1 computer and paste on the other one.

It's cross-platform: Windows, Linux and Mac OS X. [Windows 7 is supported](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/wiki/Requirements).
It's free and open-source too.

Comment: simply the best :) +1

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out and it looks really amazing!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will suit your needs, but have you considered [Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com/)?

It allows you to define a folder, which everything in it will be in both computers.

Answer (score 1):

Most remote control protocols (VNC, RDC) support sharing textual data via clipboard integration. I've not encountered anything that supports transferring image data directly via clipboard integration.

Some VNC variants support transferring files between client and server if correctly configured. Windows' Remote Desktop supports transferring any files via copy+paste (if there is a client for MacOS that supports this feature).

Your other option is just to open a network file share on one of the machines and transfer the data that way.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension that can do this in Firefox:

> [Copy and Paste extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10489)